# Why no multiple return values in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What's the rationale for the lack of multiple return value support in Clojure? (Clojure doesn't seem to have anything similar to Common Lisp's `values`/`multiple-value-bind`)

Is explicit destructuring considered more idiomatic in a functional programming style, does it have something to do with the JVM, or was it simply thought to be too much complexity for too little gain?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are already familiar with basic Clojure destructing with vectors & maps:

```
(defn calc-sqr-vec [x]
  [ x  (* x x) ])         ; returns a vector of 2 values

(defn calc-sqr-map [x]
  { :x x  :y (* x x) })   ; returns a map of 2 entries

(let [ [x y] (calc-sqr-vec 3) ]
  (println (format "3^2 -> [%d,%d]" x y)))

(let [ {:keys [x y]} (calc-sqr-map 3) ]
  (println (format "3^2 -> [%d,%d]" x y)))

vec: 3^2 => [3,9]
map: 3^2 => [3,9]
```

where you wrap the ***two*** return values `x` & `y` in a ***single*** vector or map, and the caller pulls out the component values when desired.

I cannot answer the `why` part in relation to CL, but one big benefit compared to the Python-style multiple return values is the question of what to do when the user doesn't specify all the return values. For example:

```
q, r = divmod(22, 7)
q => 3
r => 1

q = divmod(22, 7)
q => (3,1)
```

So, in Python the same expression `divmod(22, 7)` generates **different** results that depend on the "receiving" part of the statement. This type of complexity is avoided by always returning the same, single value and allowing the caller the choice of when & how to pull out the desired bits (and ignore unwanted bits).

---

Update

It's interesting that this topic came today, since just yesterday I was working with functions that needed to return a bunch of separate values.  I wrote a short macro to make it easier. The unit test shows it in action:

```
(dotest
  (let [some-fn (fn []
                  (let [a 1
                        b 2
                        c 3
                        d 4
                        e 5]
                    (label-value-map a b c d e))) ]
    (is= {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5} (some-fn))
    (let [ {:keys [a b c d e]} (some-fn) ]
      (is= [a b c d e] [1 2 3 4 5]))))
```

So using `label-value-map` and the plain-old `{:keys [a b c d e]}` destructuring you can transfer a bunch of scalar values from one place to another with less typing.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed examples :) In my case, I was mainly wondering about the why (rationale). Common Lisp's `multiple-value-bind` simply binds the extra variables to nil if the function didn't return that many values. As does Clojure's destructuring: `(let [[a b c] [1 2]] c) => nil`. Python doesn't really have multiple return values either - it just has syntactic sugar that allows people to omit the parentheses from tuples so that they don't look like tuples. `divmod` always returns a tuple of two values. `q, r = <any expression that returns a tuple or list>` is sugar for unpacking items.

Comment: Compared to returning arrays and objects multiple return really don't give you anything but the fact that it stays on the stack and doesn't allocate heap memory. It's only an optimization. In Scheme I rather not use them since the implementation is made so much harder to use than CL.

Comment: I don't buy the argument about returning different values depending on whether the user specifies bindings for all the return values. Your example in Python just shows `divmod` returning a 2-tuple, with `x, y = f(a)` being the syntax for destructuring it, and `x = f(a)` the syntax for binding the whole tuple. A Clojure `divmod` returning a 2-vector would look the same, just with Clojure destructuring syntax being (of course) different.

Comment: That is, Python, like Clojure, doesn't really have multiple return values. It just has tuple returns, and a convenient way to destructure them if you want. Common Lisp's feature is, I believe, different, in that you have to ask explicitly for return values beyond the first, and otherwise they vanish. For example even if `g` returns multiple values, `f` only sees one of them in `(f (g x))`, whereas in Clojure or Python the whole tuple would propagate.

Comment: @Sylwester Multiple return values are not just an optimization, they have different semantics and style. CL's standard functions use the "primary" return value for the "most important" thing returned, the "secondary" value for something extra that's only useful occasionally. @amalloy is correct: everything but the primary value is discarded unless you explicitly bind them with `multiple-value-bind` and its kin. Lua also has real multiple values like that: https://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html

Comment: @Lassi I agree CL adds some value with the use of the possible other values being optional, but if you look at Scheme it does not provide this feature. True multiple return values would need [support by the jvm](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4222792).

Answer (score 1):

We can speculate about the why, but looking at the capabilities of Clojure in this area I think we can say it simply does not need multiple return values.

Out of the box, there are two basic ways of emulating multiple returns in Clojure: composite values for destructuring, and dynamically bound auxiliary returns.

Here is the **destructuring** style, where all results are returned eagerly and can be destructured by the caller as desired:

```
(defn foo
  "Returns a map with results at keys :ret and :aux."
  []
  {:ret :primary, :aux :auxiliary})

(let [{:keys [ret]} (foo)]
  (vector ret))                 ; => [:primary]
(let [{:keys [ret aux]} (foo)]
  (vector ret aux))             ; => [:primary :auxiliary]
```

Here is the **dynamic var auxiliary return** style, where optional results are opt-in (caller signals interest) and returned via side channel:

```
(def ^:dynamic *foo-aux* nil)

(defn foo
  "Returns result, and auxiliary result in *foo-aux* if bound."
  []
  (when (thread-bound? #'*foo-aux*)
    (set! *foo-aux* :auxiliary))
  :primary)

(vector (foo))                ; => [:primary]
(binding [*foo-aux* nil]
  (let [ret (foo)]
    (vector ret *foo-aux*)))  ; => [:primary :auxiliary]
```

Depending on the style, results are computed and returned eagerly, or explicitly asked for by the caller and thus computed on demand. Both styles allow callers to pick and choose results à la carte.

Comment: *You* are a wild man! Reminds me of C, where we optionally passed a pointer to a location where the called function could write auxiliary data. A dynamic var is certainly a workaround, all wildness aside.

Comment: Thank you, @DirkGeurs, I had missed that. Now that I think about it though, I don’t see what advantage the metadata approach would have over the composite value + destructuring approach – it works only for return values that support `meta`, such as maps and vectors, so applicability is quite narrow, isn’t it?

Comment: @kennytilton I’m going to have to come clean and admit that I didn’t invent this trick. I first saw it in *Clojure programming* from O’Reilly and then in a talk by Chas Emerick, where he calls it a legitimate use of dynamic vars … so at least we have it on authority that it may not be as outlandish as it first seems.

Comment: @gits It sure is a shame that this doesn't work for all data types.

Comment: Meanwhile, I think we have a good example of how a workaround demonstrating a language does not need X is the best demonstration of the need for X.

Comment: Have to concur, just wow! :D The "dynamic var auxiliary return style" made my morning :) Using special variables, threads, and variable assignment in a functional language just to return a value from a function. Is there any practical problem for which it is the cleanest solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer *why* is because it doesn't *need* a multiple value support and the reason is doesn't *need* one is because one can be easily written with macros. I work mostly in Common Lisp and know some Clojure but its seems that you are probably correct about it being more idiomatic. Clojure where has more included support of maps and vectors and destructuring them than Common Lisp does, so it is easier, safer, and probably more efficient to manually destructure rather than include a version of `multiple-value-bind` and `values`.

On a side note, I rarely use `values` and `multiple-value-bind` except when it makes more idiomatic sense that a function would "naturally" return a single value, like in the case of `(mod 5 4)`, where only sometimes I want the second value.

Comment: Neither macros nor destructuring are a replacement for multiple values (and I am missing them badly just now). You even explain why: calling code can just pretend the other values are not there, but a particular caller can look for them, and a particular invocation can selectively supply them. The last is what I need since there is only one caller (but hundreds of anonymous functions most of which will return just the core value). Since I have just the one caller I will have the odd lambda return a map with suitable meta and have the caller unpack that (slowing down all with the check!).